# Button clicklistener inside listview

Tags: android

Hi am having listview which contains textview and edittext and button when am trying to add oncicklistener giving `null pointer exception` can anyone help me on this pls..

Comment: Are you using an array adapter?

Comment: post getview method of you adapter atleast..

Comment: In the future, every time you make a post and your app is throwing an `Exception`, you need to post the **log**. This is important and you should definitely learn how to read one too. Also, considering you are throwing a `NullPointerException` it would be wise to post your `Adapter` code as well, or any other relevant code. You came here for help, but you aren't giving anyone much to work with. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

If you override `ArrayAdapter`, you can use the `getView()` to set the `onClick` listener on each of the list's element's button:

```
class Arraybtton extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>
{
    @Override
    public android.view.View getView(int position, android.view.View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View elem;
        Button btn;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            elem = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_elem, parent, false);
        }
        else
        {
            elem = convertView;
        }

        RowItem itm = getItem(position);
        btn = (Button) elem.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        })

        return elem;
    }
};
}
}
```

Comment: yes i see in your comment but i share with you this option bez i'm not finding any solution with baseadapter.if you will find then good otherwise go with it

Comment: Just some code explanations/additions: You have to call `((Activity) getContext())` to gain access to the `getLayoutInflater()` method. Additionally you need to initialize the views in your list item (e.g. `((TextView) elem.findViewById(textViewResourceId)).setText(itm.toString())`. To prevent confusion (I didn't understand this at first, too): `RowItem` is no Android/Java class - it simply stands for the class you use to fill the ArrayAdapter (e.g. `String`).

Comment: And of course you have to specify at least one constructor, normally `public Arraybttn(Context ctx, int listViewRes, int txtViewRes, List<RowItem> items)` should be sufficient.