# How do I add an OnClickListener to a button inside a ListView adapter?

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

I have a listview that contains the list of all my users. Every item from the list is a layout that has a button to show an AlertDialog to change the value of the label of the button. How can I dynamically add an on click event to that button that is generated by the listview Adapter?

This is my adapter:

```
public class PerfilAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
List<PerfilBean> listaPerfiles = new ArrayList<PerfilBean>();
public Settings01 set=new Settings01();
public PerfilAdapter(Context context,List<PerfilBean> lista) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listaPerfiles=lista;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listaPerfiles.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listaPerfiles.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RelativeLayout itemView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        itemView = (RelativeLayout) mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.item_perfil, parent, false);
    } else {
        itemView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }
    // obtengo los valores de la vista
    Button moneda = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Moneda);
    TextView titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Titulo);
    TextView nombredesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
    TextView descripcion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
    String nombreM = Metodos.monedas[listaPerfiles.get(position).getPerfil_tipoMoneda()];
    moneda.setText(nombreM);
    titulo.setText(listaPerfiles.get(position).getPerfil_nombre());
    nombredesc.setText(listaPerfiles.get(position).getPerfil_nombreSec());
    descripcion.setText(listaPerfiles.get(position).getPerfil_texto());

    return itemView;

}
// metodo parahacer la vista de la celda


    public void actualizaDatosLista(List<PerfilBean> listaPerfilesM) {
        for(int i=0;i<listaPerfilesM.size();i++){
            Log.d("ITEM "+i,listaPerfilesM.get(i).getPerfil_nombreSec());
        }
        listaPerfiles = listaPerfilesM;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }}
```

and this is my Activity:

```
public class Settings01 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private List<PerfilBean> lst;
private PerfilDAO perfildao;
private PerfilAdapter perfiladapter;
private ListView lstPerfiles;

public void changeMoneda(final int position) {
    int x = 0;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings01.this);
    builder.setTitle("Seleccione Tipo de Distribuidor");
    builder.setItems(R.array.moneda, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            lst.get(position).setPerfil_tipoMoneda(item);
            perfiladapter = new PerfilAdapter(getApplicationContext(), lst);
            lstPerfiles.setAdapter(perfiladapter);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings01);
    lstPerfiles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstSettings);
    perfildao = new PerfilDAOImplDB(Settings01.this);
    lst = new ArrayList<PerfilBean>();
    lst = perfildao.getAll();
    perfiladapter = new PerfilAdapter(getApplicationContext(), lst);
    Log.d("Info", "En Settings");
    lstPerfiles.setAdapter(perfiladapter);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Info", "derp" + v.getId());

}}
```

This is the layout that my adapter is currently using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Titulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/Negro"
    android:text="derp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblTipoMoneda"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Moneda"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="Tipo de moneda: " />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Moneda"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/Blanco"
    android:textColor="@color/Negro"
    android:text="Peso argentino" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Separador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2.5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Moneda"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:background="@color/Negro" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Nombre"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Separador"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:onClick="changeMoneda"
    android:text="Nombre :" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Separador"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Nombre"
    android:background="@drawable/fondotxt"
    android:textColor="@color/Negro"
    android:inputType="text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblTitulo"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNombre"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblTitulo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Negro"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPicturefantes"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/lblFotoAntes"
    android:src="@drawable/what" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPicturefdespues"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/centerPoint"
    android:src="@drawable/what" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblFotoDespues"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPicturefdespues"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Foto despues: "
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnDespuesF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnAntesF"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPicturefdespues"
    android:background="@drawable/btnupload" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblFotoAntes"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtDescripcion"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Foto antes: "
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnAntesF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblFotoAntes"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint"
    android:background="@drawable/btnupload" />
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10357063/1868912

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do so in the `getView()` method of your adapter. For that you will need to use a custom adapter (if you are not doing that already). It will be better if you can show the relevant portions of your code.

**EDIT:**
The dialog will be shown by your activity. So you can create an interface for listening to this button click event.

```
public interface BtnClickListener {
    public abstract void onBtnClick(int position);
}
```

Let your custom adapter receive it as input.

```
private BtnClickListener mClickListener = null;
public PerfilAdapter(Context context, List<PerfilBean> lista, BtnClickListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listaPerfiles=lista;
    mClickListener = listener;
}
```

Now you can simply set the normal `onClickListener` in `getView()` as below

```
Button moneda = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Moneda);
moneda.setTag(position); //For passing the list item index
moneda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mClickListener != null)
            mClickListener.onBtnClick((Integer) v.getTag());                
    }
});
```

Let your activity pass the required BtnClickListener as part of adapter creation.

```
perfiladapter = new PerfilAdapter(getApplicationContext(), lst, new BtnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBtnClick(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Call your function which creates and shows the dialog here
        changeMoneda(position);
    }

});
```

Assuming that `lst.get(position).setPerfil_tipoMoneda(item);` changes the text which will be used as button text correctly, you should simply call `perfiladapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onClick` of your `dialog` (Currently you are creating the adapter again which is not required).

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    lst.get(position).setPerfil_tipoMoneda(item);
    perfiladapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Hope it will work as you expect it to.

Comment: i have an custom adapter but i need the adapter to have the Button Moneda have to appear a alerdialog to show option after the user select the label of the button have to change that depends of the selection

Comment: Thanks a lot man... You have explained it very well. I was also stuck with the similar issue, but you saved me..

Comment: How do you call notifyDataSetChanged from The MainActivity ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had to add this attribute in the listView :

```
<ListView
...
android:clickable="true"
...
</ListView>
```

And in the adapter just add on click listener in the button view.

```
wrapper.getButtonHi().setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DebugUtils.logDebug("Clickeado :: "+ mContact.getUserId());
        }
});
```

Its important to set final the variables:

```
public View getRowView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final BrowseContactItemWrapper wrapper;
    final UserModel mContact = lstContact.get(position);
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small tweak to refresh the renderer from outside.

```
final FinalMenuListAdapter adapter = this;

viewHolder.deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       if(mClickListener != null)
         mClickListener.onBtnClick((MenuItemObject)v.getTag(),adapter);
   }
 });
 final MenuItemObject menuItemObject = getItem(position);

 viewHolder.deleteItem.setTag(menuItemObject);
```