# How to wire up a delete button to delete one item on a listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, arraylist

I know there are lots of threads with more or less same topic but none of them covers my situation:

I am trying to get my delete button to delete one row on the list view and the delete button appear in each row I got this part to work but I can't get it  to work in my Main Activity. The code keeps breaking every time I put this part in my code:

```
ImageButton removeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onRemoveButtonClick();
    }
    private void  onRemoveButtonClick() {
        ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) v.getTag();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

my `MainActivity` works fine without this bit of code. I don't know if it is the code or if it is where I am placing it in my `MainActivity` if someone would please tell that would much appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ToDoApp";
    private ToDoListManager listManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView todoList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.todo_list);
        listManager = new ToDoListManager(getApplicationContext());
        ToDoItemAdapter adapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, listManager.getList());


        todoList.setAdapter(adapter);
        ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_item);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onAddButtonClick();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        listManager.saveList();
    }

    private void onAddButtonClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.add_item);

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.ok,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //Add item to list
                    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem(
                            input.getText().toString(),
                            false
                    );
                    listManager.addItem(item);
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, input.getText().toString());
                }
            });
        builder.setNegativeButton(
            R.string.cancel,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

        builder.show();
    }

    private class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

        private  Context context;
        private List<ToDoItem> items;
        public ToDoItemAdapter(Context context, List<ToDoItem> items){
            super(context,-1,  items);

            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_item_layout, parent, false);
            }

            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            textView.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
            checkBox.setChecked(items.get(position).isComplete());

            convertView.setTag(items.get(position));
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ToDoItem item = (ToDoItem) v.getTag();
                    item.toggleComplete();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

**ToDoListManager.java**

```
public class ToDoListManager {


private static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "todoapp";
private static final String TODO_ITEMS = "itemslist";

private List<ToDoItem> items;
private SharedPreferences savedData;

public  ToDoListManager(Context context) {

     savedData = context.getSharedPreferences (
        APP_PREFERENCES,
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    );

    String json = savedData.getString(TODO_ITEMS, null);
    if (json == null) {
    items = new ArrayList<>();
  } else {

 Type type = new TypeToken<List<ToDoItem>>() {}.getType();
 items = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
}


}
 public List<ToDoItem> getList() {
 return items;
 }
 public void  addItem(ToDoItem item) {
    items.add(item);
    saveList();

 }
 public  void saveList() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit =savedData.edit();
    edit.clear();
    String json = new Gson().toJson(items);

    edit.putString(TODO_ITEMS, json);
    edit.apply();
 }

}
```

**ToDoItem.java**

```
public class ToDoItem {
private String description;
private boolean isComplete;

public ToDoItem (String description,boolean isComplete) {
    this.description = description;
    this.isComplete = isComplete;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return  description;
}
public boolean isComplete() {
    return isComplete;
}
public void toggleComplete() {
    isComplete = !isComplete;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrwqb.png)

Comment: If you want each row of the list view to have a delete button that removes that item you will need to add the clickListener in your adapter. Can you share your `ToDoItemAdapter` code with us?

Comment: it within my MainActivity.java at the top in code.

Comment: As Dr. Nitpick says, you need to set each button's `OnClickListener` in the adapter's `getView()` method. He is also asking for the code for the `ToDoItemAdapter` class, not the declaration for the reference variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add an onclicklistener to a button inside a listview adapter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132359/how-do-i-add-an-onclicklistener-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-adapter)

Comment: I have just added all of my code to the thread please help.

Comment: @M.Bill , The adapter is responsible to showing the view that you need. In that you have a checkbox, a title but you `don't have the button you need to delete that row`.

Comment: can you show me what to do in code form. I am new to this and it is hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Add a button to your to_do_item_layout first

2.) Now add this code to add a button to each item

```
Button btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
```

3.) Add a listener to it

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         items.remove(items.get(position));         
      }
});
```

Comment: thanks do I put it at the end of my main activity after return convertView; ?

Comment: in your TodoItemAdapter class inside the getView method

Comment: ok so I did as you said and after ruining it, it crashed when you press the the button don't know why.

Comment: Thank you so much it works I just have one question for you I have a little garbage can for the delete button but it always disappears off the screen if the line of the text is too long and if its too short it's attached to the line know what I mean and I just wanted to be on the right hand side of the app I'll see if I can add an image to show you what I mean just if I'm not clear if you can solve this last problem for me you're a lifesaver thanks again for the delete code

Comment: Make sure that the text is aliged to the left of the delete button. It is occupying complete space that is why the trash can disappears.

Comment: sorry can you show me in code format please. i added the image for you to  get a better understanding of what I mean. its the "enter image description here" link thanks