# Get groupPosition of expanded child in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview

I'm implementing an ExpandableListView with a numberPicker in every child of the list, like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nroG.png).

Now, when I click on the button, i have to get te text from the editText beside the button.
The problem is when there is more than one child expanded, if I click the button of the child which is not the last being expanded, the button collects the text of the last child expanded.
Therefore, I want to get the groupPosition in which there is the button I click.

Here is my code:

```
public void buttonOK_OnClick(View view){
    buttonOK = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.buttonOK);
    EditText editText = DepositAdapter.getnumberPickerDisplayDeposit();
    String myText = editText.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class DepositAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions = ProductsListActivity.getDb_transaction().read(context, 2);
    private static View view;

    public DepositAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return transactions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        // se l'elemento è cliccato allora return 0 altrimenti return 1
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        Product product = LoginActivity.getDb_products().checkProduct(transactions.get(groupPosition).getBarcode());

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(product.getName() + "\nEAN: " + transactions.get(groupPosition).getBarcode());
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }
        view = convertView;
        final EditText e = getnumberPickerDisplayDeposit();
        e.setText(String.valueOf(transactions.get(groupPosition).getQuantity()));
        e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                // TODO auto-generated method stub!
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                // TODO auto-generated method stub!
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable edt) {
                String quantity = String.valueOf(transactions.get(groupPosition).getQuantity() + 1);
                // viene controllato se l'utente inserisce 0, valore non possibile, allora il valore viene sostituito con 1
                if (edt.toString().equals(quantity))
                    e.setText(String.valueOf(transactions.get(groupPosition).getQuantity()));
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    public static EditText getnumberPickerDisplayDeposit(){
        EditText textViewNumberPickerDisplayDeposit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.numberPickerDisplayDeposit);
        return textViewNumberPickerDisplayDeposit;
    }
}
```

Comment: POST your full adapter class.

Comment: Create an interface in your Adapter and then implement it in your activity to get the position.

Comment: You should create an interface in your Adapter and then implement it in your activity to get the position. For more information see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132359/how-do-i-add-an-onclicklistener-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-adapter).

Comment: But I cannot understand what I have to do in the override method in my activity, to get the position.