# How do I detect if a button from an activity is clicked while inside a RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have this method in my activity (`CreatePhotostoryActivity`):

```
@Override
public void showEditField(Moment oldMoment, final int index){
    listRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    editCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    saveCancelNavbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    momentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    photoStoryNavbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(oldMoment.photoUri).into(displayPhoto);

    imageCaption.setText("");


    imageCaption.setText(oldMoment.caption);

    backIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeEditMoment();
        }
    });

    saveText.setText("Save Moment");

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateMoment(imageCaption.getText().toString(), index);
            Intent i = new Intent(CreatePhotostoryActivity.this, RVAdapter.class);
            i.putExtra("isSaved", true);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            closeEditMoment();
            Intent i = new Intent(CreatePhotostoryActivity.this, RVAdapter.class);
            i.putExtra("isSaved", false);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

In my `RecyclerView` adapter, `showEditField` is called using an interface, and it does work except that I am unable to detect whether `saveButton` or `cancelButton` was clicked. This is how it's called in the `onBindViewHolder` method of my `RecyclerView` adapter (`RVAdapter`):

```
((RecyclerView.ViewHolder) momentViewHolder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mAdapterCallback.showEditField(moments.get(position), position);
        Intent intent = ((CreatePhotostoryActivity) mContext).getIntent();
        Boolean isSaved = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isSaved");
        if (isSaved) {
            holder.momentCaption.setText(moments.get(position).caption);
            holder.momentPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.momentCaption.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.momentPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.momentCaption.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

Do note my attempt of using an intent to find out which button was clicked. It doesn't work. `momentCaption` remains gone and `momentPlaceHolder` remains visible even though `saveButton` was clicked. The app also crashes afterwards.

Edit: I think calling this `mAdapterCallback.showEditField(moments.get(position), position);` before setting the values of `momentCaption` and `momentPlaceholder` is problematic, since `showEditField` calls other methods (e.g. `closeEditMoment()` before the intent is retrieved from the adapter.

Comment: Have look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132359/how-do-i-add-an-onclicklistener-to-a-button-inside-a-listview-adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a global variable inside recyclerView adapter:

```
    RecyclerViewAdapter {
    private boolean isSaveButtonClicked = false;
    private boolean isCancelButtonClicked = false;

    public void saveButtonClicked(){
    isSaveButtonClicked = true;
    }}

    public void cancelButtonClicked(){
    isCancelButtonClicked = true;
    }}
```

When your activity call onclickListeners , you will notice your adapter.

```
     CreatePhotostoryActivity(){

     private RecyclerView adapter;

     onSaveButtonClicked(){
     adapter.saveButtonClicked();
     }

    onCancelButtonClicked(){
    adapter.cancelButtonClicked();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an `interface` with two methods like `saveBtnClick()` and `cancelBtnClick()`.

Implement the `interface` in your `Activity`.

Implement Click listener for both the buttons in the `ViewHolder` of your `RecyclerView` and call the Appropriate methods using `Inteface's` Object.

//Interface

```
 public interface ManageButtonClicks
 {
  void saveBtnClick();
 }
```

//Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements ManageButtonClicks
{
       ManageButtonClicks manageButtonClicks=this;
       MyAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);
   //Do the operations
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this,adapterList,manageButtonClicks);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
  void saveBtnClick()
  {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

//Adapter Class

```
   public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>
   {
    ManageButtonClicks manageButtonClicks;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List< ModelClass > data, ManageButtonClicks manageButtonClicks)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mDataList = data;
    this.ctx = context;
    util = new Util(ctx);
    this.manageButtonClicks = manageButtonClicks;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{

    ViewGroup nonPrimeRow = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME holderNonPrime = new MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME(nonPrimeRow);
    return holderNonPrime;
}
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position)
    {
    ModelClass current = mDataList.get(position);
    MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME holder_not_prime = (MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME) holder;
    holder_not_prime.setdata(current);
}
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

public class MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME extends MyViewHolder
{

    private Button btnSave;

    public MyViewHolder_NON_PRIME(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        btnSave = (MonteButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    }

    public void setdata(final ModelClass current)
    {
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                manageButtonClicks.saveBtnClick();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but `saveButton` and `cancelButton` are only referenced in the activity.

Comment: Correct Me if I am wrong. I am assuming that you are having a RecyclerView with a custom row with 2 buttons Save and Cancel. You want to do some certain operations on each button clicks. Am I right.?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Comment: Try The Edited Answer. Even I wanted to do something like this earlier.